# Check if a list contains all of another lists items when comparing on one property

Tags: c#, list, linq, any

I am learning Linq and I have two object lists. I want to compare one of these lists against the other to see if all of one of the properties of the objects within it can be matched to those in the other list.
So, I provide code for that but I want to change it to Linq expressions.

```
var list1 = new List<Product>
{
    new Product{SupplierId = 1,ProductName = "Name1"},
    new Product{SupplierId = 2,ProductName = "Name2"},
    new Product{SupplierId = 3,ProductName = "Name3"},
    new Product{SupplierId = 4,ProductName = "Name4"}
};

var list2 = new List<Product>
{
    new Product {SupplierId = 1,ProductName = "Name5"},
    new Product {SupplierId = 4,ProductName = "Name6"}
};

private static bool CheckLists(List<Product> list1, List<Product> list2)
{
    foreach (var product2 in list2)
    {
        bool result = false;
        foreach (var product in list1)
        {
            if (product.SupplierId == product2.SupplierId)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!result)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I do it using LINQ?

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using `Contains`?

Comment: @NetMage For using `Contains` he should override `Equals`

Comment: For extra clarity, for anyone reading this subsequently, the check being done is whether all the items in list2 can be found in list1.

Answer (score 36):

```
bool existsCheck = list1.All(x => list2.Any(y => x.SupplierId == y.SupplierId));
```

would tell you if all of list1's items are in list2.

Comment: The most readable solution. Why does everyone complicate things?

Comment: This solution really makes sense. I'd recommend this one as my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You want to check whether there are any IDs in `list1` that aren't in `list2`:

```
if (list1.Select(p => p.SupplierId).Except(list2.Select(p => p.SupplierId)).Any())
```

Comment: I think you have `list1` and `list2` backwards.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not sure this is correct; if you change '4' in List2 to '5' won't this will still return true whereas the original code sample would return false?

Comment: Like NetMage says he's checking if there are any IDs in List2 which aren't in List1, not the other way round, so I think these need reversing and a '!' adding

Answer (score 0):

To see that `list1` contains all of `list2`, check if `Any` of `list1` matches `All` of `list2`:

```
private static bool CheckLists(List<Product> list1, List<Product> list2) => list2.All(l2p => list1.Any(l1p => l1p.SupplierId == l2p.SupplierId));
```

However, I would probably write an generic extension method:

```
public static class Ext {
    static public bool ContainsAll<T, TKey>(this List<T> containingList, List<T> containee, Func<T, TKey> key) {
        var HSContainingList = new HashSet<TKey>(containingList.Select(key));
        return containee.All(l2p => HSContainingList.Contains(key(l2p)));
    }
    static public bool ContainsAll<T>(this List<T> containingList, List<T> containee) => containingList.ContainsAll(containee, item => item);
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
var ans = list1.ContainsAll(list2, p => p.SupplierId);
```